# How to do a post request with parameters passed in Sencha touch2.2?

Tags: json, rest, extjs, sencha-touch, http-post

I am trying to do a POST request using Sencha Architect which expects some parameters. I gave that in extra parameters. But when i load the data in store, it says method not allowed(error 405). My Store is

```
config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
        storeId: 'MyJsonPStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            extraParams: {
                credentials: {
                    password: 'XXX',
                    ipAddress: '000.0.0.0',
                    deviceType: 'ZZZ',
                    username: 'ABCD',
                    clientVersion: '2.0.0.0',
                    clientHelpVersion: null
                }
            },
            url: 'http://abcd.com/login/',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'userLogin'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the request method by using "actionMetods" in your store :

(set proxy, api, writer, etc...and add : )

```
actionMethods:  
    {
        create: 'POST', 
        read: 'POST',
        update: 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
```

Comment: I am using Sencha Architect where I can't edit my code and I don't find a place to add actionMethods using the tool.

Comment: There seems to be an answer to that on the sencha forum : [http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?180006-AjaxProxy-actionMethods]